# How to properly scale of GameObjects in ARCore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

If I have a scene with models scaled properly relative to one another, for example a sphere with a diameter of 0.2 meters, scale equal to `Vector3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)`, how do I insure that if I add that sphere into the sample ARCore, it will be same scale, ei. 0.2 meters in diameter in the real world.

Currently, everything get's scaled down and I'm only replacing the Andy prefab with my sphere prefab.

Comment: Check the scale of the parent object. You are most likely placing the sphere object under a parent object and that one may have been scaled down initially. So if the parent object is 0.5 and your sphere is 0.2 then your sphere is actually 0.1.

Comment: You're right. It was the scale of the parent. Thanks!